# using paintComponent method in JApplet

Tags: java, swing, applet, awt, paintcomponent

I have create a program in Java which allows dragging of two oval shapes. Now I want to convert it to a `JApplet` so I made the class extend `JApplet` instead of original `JPanel`. The problem with this is that `super.paintComponent(g)` does not work as it is no longer a parent class.

I have tried creating a `JPanel` within the class then referring to this but I get the error: The method `paintComponent(Graphics)` from the type `JComponent` is not visible

Any heads up on what I need to do or any help would be much appreciated thanks.

Here is my code.

```
public class Main extends JPanel 
{
    private static final String TITLE = "Drag me!";
    private static final int W = 640;
    private static final int H = 480;
    private Point origin = new Point(W / 2, H / 2);
    private Point mousePt;
    public Main() {

    this.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
    this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() 
    {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) 
            {
                mousePt = e.getPoint();
                repaint();
            }
        });
    this.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() 
    {
            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) 
            {
                int dx = e.getX() - mousePt.x;
                int dy = e.getY() - mousePt.y;
                origin.setLocation(origin.x + dx, origin.y + dy);
                mousePt = e.getPoint();
                repaint();
            }
    });
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(W, H);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawOval(0, origin.y, getWidth(), origin.y);
        g.drawOval(origin.x, 0, origin.x, getHeight());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame f = new JFrame(TITLE);
                f.add(new Main());
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                f.pack();
                f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I have also tried using the repaint method but this keeps rewriting the oval on the screen like a trail.

Comment: You must have had a `JFrame` in your original program as well. The `JApplet` should replace the `JFrame`. Any class that you created by extending `JPanel` should not have to be modified. If this does not help, maybe you could provide more code.

Comment: You might have to override `paint(Graphics g)` instead of `paintComponent(Graphics g)`. Not sure though.. And indeed check if there are no `JFrames` or other window things, like @Marco13 said.

Comment: @Creator13 You should override the `paintComponent` method, not the `paint`.  The `paintComponent` method gives double buffering whereas the `paint` method will not.  I actually think that the `paint` method for JComponents calls the `paintComponent` method.

Comment: I see you added the code, but this was nearly at the same time as Jared gave an answer. It should basically as easy as he described it in your case: The `main` method and the `JFrame` will be no longer required. Instead you create a new class extending `JApplet` and add your `Main` JPanel as the content pane.

Comment: @user3109178 I really think you should always use `setContentPane` for both applets and applications (i.e. `JFrame`).  Adding components is intended to be used with a layout manager.  You shouldn't lay out your frame, rather you should just lay out a panel which would then act as your frame (after setting the content pane of a frame).

Comment: *" Now I want to convert it to a `JApplet`.."*  Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of modifying your `JPanel`, keep it and create a new class, your `JApplet` class:

```
public class YourJApplet extends JApplet{
    public void init(){
        final JPanel panel = new YourPanel();
        this.setContentPane(panel);
    }
}
```

That's it--now whatever was going on with your panel is now your JApplet.

Comment: I really hope this hammers home the point that you should create your UI via `JPanel` (although I still have yet to here an argument for why you should extend `JPanel` over `JComponent`).  Then if you want an application you create a `JFrame` and set its content pane to your panel or, if you want to create an applet, extend `JApplet` and set _its_ content pane to your panel.

Comment: Yes I understand this now, I never new that JFrame and JApplet are inherited in the same swing class. I think that was the problem.